# Is this typecast correct?

Tags: c, haskell, shared-libraries

Basically my code crashes in NucleoProf_init, judging by gdb's stack-trace, and by the fact that is the only function that I call.

```
#include <HsFFI.h>

static char *argv[] = {"NucleoProf", "", "", 0};
static int argc = 1;

HsBool NucleoProf_init(void){

   // Initialize Haskell runtime
   hs_init(&argc,  (char***)&argv );

   return HS_BOOL_TRUE;
}
```

I suspect that it is the way I pass the argv argument, or perhaps, the typecast of argv, because the stack-trace contains the following:

```
#3  0x00007ffff5956282 in setFullProgArgv ()
    from /usr/lib/ghc/libHSrts-ghc7.4.1.so
#4  0x00007ffff5956d04 in hs_init_ghc () from /usr/lib/ghc/libHSrts-ghc7.4.1.so
#5  0x00007ffff5b9ed4f in NucleoProf_init ()
```

Question: Is this the correct way of "synthesizing" a trivial command line?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try this:

```
char ** p = argv;
hs_init(&argc, &p);
```

It's unclear why you would need to pass the array by address, but I don't know the API you're using. Double-check the manual to see if those values can be changed by the function and if you need to process them afterwards.

Comment: Thanks! Your solution works (accepting ASAP). I don't know either why somebody would have things passed this way...

Comment: @dsign: As I said, read the documentation. It's possible that the `argc` value will be modified (e.g. to discount "consumed" arguments), and perhaps something similar is the case for `argv`.

Comment: Here is all the documentation I could find: http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.2/html/users_guide/ffi-ghc.html , it doesn't say a lot in this sense.   Apparently I'm missing something or the docs are wrong, because that typecast does not compile. But I agree that most likely they will try to remove some special options from argv.

Comment: @dsign: The docs you have linked contain errors in the second example. The first example is correct because `char *argv[]` is used in *function parameter list* (of `main`), where it actually stands for `char **argv`, so `&argv` correctly produces `char ***`. In the second example they declare a true array `char *argv[N]`. For a true array, `&argv` produces `char *(*argv)[N]` pointer. This will not work where a `char ***` is required. And an explicit cast to `char ***` will not make it work. You have to create a pointer first and then take its address, as suggested in the above answer.

Comment: @dsign "We pass references to `argc` and `argv` to `hs_init()` so that it can separate out any arguments for the RTS (i.e. those arguments between +RTS...-RTS)." <- that's why.

Comment: @DanielFischer: That doesn't *really* explain why we need the `argv` array by reference. `getopt` also reorders and removes arguments, but it can do so without the extra indirection. `argv` is typically already a pointer!

Comment: True, only a pointer to `argc` is _needed_ (unless `hs_init()` does funky things), but that's - as far as I can gather - the reasoning that led to `hs_init()`'s signature. The reasoning is probably faulty, but changing the signature now would break a lot of code.

Answer (score 2):

It's wrong because, firstly, it's the wrong type. Taking the address of an array results in a pointer to an array. `&argv` has type `char *(*)[4]`, i.e. "a pointer to an array of 4 pointers to char". This is not the `char ***` type that you want. You are forcibly casting it to hide the type incompatibility.

You want a `char ***`, which is a pointer to an actual `char **` variable. But you do not have a `char **` variable anywhere. You have `argv`, a `char *[4]` variable, which is completely different. An array variable is just that -- a collection of its elements in sequence in memory; there is no address of anything stored anywhere in memory.

Your fundamental confusion might be the fact that **arrays are not pointers**. Arrays have different sizes (the size of an array is its length times size of its component type), pointer and array types (pointer to an array is very different from from a pointer to a pointer; same with array of arrays and array of pointers), and semantics (arrays cannot be assigned or passed). An array expression can implicitly *degrade* to a pointer rvalue in some situations; but in this case, you are taking the address, which needs an lvalue, so it does not apply. Never confuse arrays with pointers.